# Connect and process oracle data from Objective-C on Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, oracle

I am looking for any resources or examples, to connect to an Oracle database and fetch large amounts of data and process/display using Cocoa/Objective-C.

Is there any way without ODBC with native Cocoa API, or I have to go thru the perl / C++ OCI calls only?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where Perl fits in but I'd definitely go with OCI since it is a C based API that should plug into Objective-C just fine.

Here's the link to the Oracle Instant Client which should have the headers and libraries you need:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html

And here is the OCI docs on how to actually use the thing:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index.html