# Data communication between Oracle server database and iOS client app

Tags: objective-c, oracle, oracle11g, relational-database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've installed Oracle Server database 11g in my PC and my iOS app can communicate with the server (send and receive msg via socket streaming). I've also installed SQL Developer from Oracle and connected the database to the server. The client device (iPhone) needs to send some data (data from some sensors, eg. geomagnetic sensor in iPhone) to the server database and download the same data (stored at database) from the server when required. For this purpose I read some threads on StackOverflow:

[Connect and process oracle data from Objective-C on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700743/connect-and-process-oracle-data-from-objective-c-on-mac-os/4701205)

[Connecting to Oracle from iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740856/connecting-to-oracle-from-ios-app)

[Oracle access from iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594751/oracle-access-from-ios)

https://odbcrouter.com/iosvsweb#hn_iOS_Open_Database_Connectivity_SDK

Some thread suggest using OCI: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index.html

I know that direct connection between iOS client and Oracle database is not possible (at least not recommended for security reason), apart from using Oracle server, is there anything more to install? Can somebody provide a sample code or some links? I use objective-c for iOS application development.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using OJDBC. It can be done by adding the ojdbc.14.jar file as Referenced Libraries on the package explorer of Eclipse workplace. Later on, a connection session can be established with the database with a private connection variable 'con' as:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, id, pw);
```

where, 'id' and 'pw' are the server ID and Password, and the 'url' can be set as:

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
```

Now, queries can be written for Adding, Deleting and Updating the database.

For more info:

https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-oracle-database
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

Edit: For detailed study this link [https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/dist/ch07_02.htm] is very helpful.